# Ограничить дочерний блок svg в максимальной ширине

Tags: html, css, svg

```
  <style>
    .container {width:30vw; height:30vh}
    .arrow_b .fons {fill:#4C4C4C}
    .arrow path {
      fill:white;
      animation-duration: 1.2s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite
    }
    
    [data-side=right\]  path:nth-child(1) {animation-name: arrow-1}
    [data-side=right\]  path:nth-child(2) {animation-name: arrow-2}
    [data-side=right\] path:nth-child(3) {animation-name: arrow-3}
    
    
    @keyframes arrow-1 {
      0% {opacity: 0}
      17% {opacity: .9}
      33% {opacity: .6}
      50% {opacity: .3}
      67% {opacity: .3}
      83% {opacity: .3}
      to {opacity: 0}
    }
    
    @keyframes arrow-2 {
      0% {opacity: 0}
      17% {opacity: .3}
      33% {opacity: .9}
      50% {opacity: .6}
      67% {opacity: .3}
      83% {opacity: .3}
      to {opacity: 0}
    }
    
    @keyframes arrow-3 {
      0% {opacity: 0}
      17% {opacity: .3}
      33% {opacity: .3}
      50% {opacity: .9}
      67% {opacity: .6}
      83% {opacity: .3}
      to {opacity: 0}
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container" >
      <svg class="arrow_b" viewBox="0 0 36 36" data-side="right"> 
        <path class='fons' d="M 36.109639,0.01484377 1.0554877,0.05 c 0,0 -0.97551951,11.009758 -0.91400211,16.509414 0.0625,5.5875 0.89791871,19.420499 0.89791871,19.420499 L 36.112858,36.08883 Z"/>
        <g class="arrow" style='max-width: 100px;'>
          <path transform="translate(22 13)" d="M0,1.75 3.5,0 3.5,3.5z"></path>
          <path transform="translate(16 13)" d="M0,1.75 3.5,0 3.5,3.5z"></path> 
          <path transform="translate(10 13)" d="M0,1.75 3.5,0 3.5,3.5z"></path> 
        </g>
        <text x="50%" text-anchor="middle" y="22" font-size="4px" fill="white">Текwwст</text>
      </svg>        
    </div>
```

Каким образом добавить родительский блок для стрелок с текстом, так чтобы стало возможным ограничить через max-width. Максимальную его ширину, тогда когда родитель с фоном будут увеличиваться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]