# Нарисовать круг в svg

Tags: svg, inkscape

Кто может нарисовать круг под размеры viewBox="0 0 36 36", простой круг. Ни эллипсом, а под тег path.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" >  
 <circle cx="18" cy="18" r="15" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
</svg>
```

Вообще не понимаю как в Inkscape, выполнить это. Одни эллипсы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача понятна - перевод окружности из тега `circle` в идентичную окружность с помощью тега `path`.
Это действительно важно, так как анимации, например `animateMotion` - движение объекта вдоль пути, работают только с `path`

> Вообще не понимаю как в Inkscape, выполнить это. Одни эллипсы.

#1. Установить в `<ellipse cx="18" cy="18" rx="15" ry="15">` и эллипс превращается при равенстве радиусов - в окружность.  (Но это комментарий для общего понятия)

#2. С помощью векторного редактора
Чтобы получить идеальную окружность по форме нужно выполнить следующие шаги

- Написать svg с требуемыми параметрами, в частности `viewBox="0 0 36 36"`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" >  
 <circle cx="18" cy="18" r="15" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
</svg>
```

- Загрузить этот файл в векторный редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- **В верхнем меню выбрать: контур / оконтурить объект <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+C</kbd>**
- Сохранить файл в формате - `*.svg` и скопировать `path`

`d="M 33,18 A 15,15 0 0 1 18,33 15,15 0 0 1 3,18 15,15 0 0 1 18,3 15,15 0 0 1 33,18 Z"`

Ниже готовый результат:

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
heigh:30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 36 36" >  
 <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 33,18 A 15,15 0 0 1 18,33 15,15 0 0 1 3,18 15,15 0 0 1 18,3 15,15 0 0 1 33,18 Z" /> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

### UPDATE

> Это действительно важно, так как анимации, например animateMotion -
> движение объекта вдоль пути, работают только с path

Решил в качестве бонуса добавить пример анимации движения шарика вдоль круговой трассы `id="trace"`

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
heigh:30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 36 36" >  
 <path id="trace" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 33,18 A 15,15 0 0 1 18,33 15,15 0 0 1 3,18 15,15 0 0 1 18,3 15,15 0 0 1 33,18 Z" /> 
 <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="red">
   
        <animateMotion id="myanim" dur="6s" begin="0; myanim.end+1s" fill="freeze">
           <mpath xlink:href="#trace"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: Спс. Подскажешь как тут быть? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398424/Ограничить-дочерний-блок-svg-в-максимальной-ширине

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов вечером попробую ответить. Сейчас занят